# npm run prod not generating css

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack

I am using Laravel with VueJS and, for generating optimized CSS and JS, I am using `webpack.mix.js`.

When I run `npm run dev`, CSS files are generated quite fine while if I run `npm run prod`, it generates CSS of `1 byte`.

Here is my `webpack.mix.js`

```js
const {mix} = require('laravel-mix');

require('laravel-mix-merge-manifest');

let publicPath = '../../../public/themes/mytheme/assets';

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    publicPath = 'publishable/assets';
}

mix.setPublicPath(publicPath).mergeManifest();
mix.disableNotifications();

try {
    mix
        .js(__dirname + '/src/Resources/assets/js/app-core.js', 'js/velocity-custom-core.js')
        .js(
            __dirname + '/src/Resources/assets/js/app.js',
            'js/velocity-custom.js'
        )

        .copy(__dirname + '/src/Resources/assets/images', publicPath + '/images')

        .sass(
            __dirname + '/src/Resources/assets/sass/admin.scss',
            __dirname + '/' + publicPath + '/css/velocity-admin.css'
        )
        .sass(
            __dirname + '/src/Resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
            __dirname + '/' + publicPath + '/css/velocity.css',
            {includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/']}
        )

        .options({
            processCssUrls: false
        })
        .styles(
            [
                publicPath + '/css/header.css',
                publicPath + '/css/listing-style.css',
                publicPath + '/css/custom-listing-desktop-combined.css'
            ],
            __dirname + '/' + publicPath + '/css/custom-listing-desktop-combined.css'
        )
        .scripts(
            [
                publicPath + '/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js',
                publicPath + '/js/intlTelInput.min.js',
                publicPath + '/plugins/bootstrap_v5.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.js',
                publicPath + '/js/modernizr-3.11.2.min.js',
                publicPath + '/plugins/Swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js',
                publicPath + '/plugins/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.js',
                publicPath + '/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js',
                publicPath + '/js/jwt-decode.js',
            ],
            __dirname + '/' + publicPath + '/css/custom-combined.js'
        );

    if (mix.inProduction()) {
        mix.minify([__dirname + '/' + publicPath + '/css/custom-combined.css']); // Minify the combined CSS file
        mix.version();
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during asset compilation: ' + error.message);
}
```

Comment: why are you `try-catch`ing errors instead of letting the CLI handle that? Remove the `try-catch` and run it again using `npm run prod` and show us the output

Comment: I have tried with `try-catch` as well but no error was there that's why I tried to add try catch but it also not working fo rme